# Magento 2 graphql API

Tags: magento2, graphql

I am using `createEmptyCart mutation` for create customer Quote Id or Mast Id.

`createEmptyCart mutation` write in `vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls` file and use resolver file `Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CreateEmptyCart`. But in this Resolver file `$customerId = $context->getUserId();` getting blank customer id, I have not idea how to set user id or customer id in `ContextInterface`, We need to set in GraphQA query or API header.

Please let me know if anyone have idea.

Answer (score 7):

Finally found the issue, We need to set customer token to API header.

```
Authorization Bearer xxxxiuaqxih8va3wbkji691517xxxxxx
```